# Azure mobile service ".login('facebook')" calls error callback after logged in successfully?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, azure, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I have the following code which uses `WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient` and it works when testing in browser (Ripple). In Ripple(browser), the page redirects to (`$state.go('menu.events')`) after logged in as expected.

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'client', function ($scope, $state, client) {
    $scope.loginFacebook = function () {
        console.log('loginFacebook...')
        client.login("facebook").then(function (data){
            console.log('logged in succesfully..')
            $state.go('menu.events');
        }, function(error){
            console.log('login failed.');
            $scope.err = JSON.stringify(error); // error is {}
            //login failed.
            $state.go('menu.test');
        });
    };
}])
```

The `client` service.

```
.factory('client', [function () {
    var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/");
    return client;
}])
```

However, it calls the error callback and goes to `menu.test` when running as an app on Android device. It flashes very quickly with the message of "You have successfully signed in /// Return to the website" on the phone. **The `error` parameter of the error callback is an empty object `{}`**.

[image: Message box after logged in]

Comment: Did you check the console to see if the client.login promise resolved successfully or failed?

Comment: Yes, it printed and success when running in Ripple. I don't know how to check the javascript console when running as Android app in emulator.

Comment: Many such ways:
https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/different-ways-to-debug-an-ionic-app

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick test leveraging your code snippet, and it works fine on my side. I suspect it could be a configuration issue or a logic issue.

You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication for checking out whether you have configured correct for authorization with Facebook.

And meanwhile, you can leverage Chrome browser to troubleshooting the android applications with a ease. Please refer to https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ for details.

## update

When I get your issue section with blank content under **chrome**:
[image]

I enter in the application installed on the dev device, then you will see the application is captured in chrome, then click `Inspect` button
[image]

At last, you can get the debug page:
[image]

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. It seems it still call the failed callback even Azure mobile service succeeded logged in?

Comment: The configuration should be OK since testing on Ripple works fine?

Comment: Since the work flow got into the error callback function, so what is the detailed error message output in `function(error)`?

Comment: What's the easiest way to get the `error` of `function(error)` on the native app? The error callback is invoked only in the native app.

Comment: Could you try the troubleshooting method via chrome I provided in my post? For now, i think it's the easiest way to troubleshooting for native apps.

Comment: Do you know what URL I should enter when troubleshooting via chrome? It's a Cordova/ionic app.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/, I have tried on my side, it works fine with ionic app.

Comment: Yes, I'm following the link. However, I'm stuck on the step of "Screencast from Android device to development machine". Clicking the "toggle screencast button" button doesn't do anything.

Comment: I can see the mobile chrome tabs. But there is no webview tabs.

Comment: Maybe the apk file need to be built in "Debug" instead of "Release"? I will ask for a debug build.

Comment: Cannot find webview. I posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113988/android-remote-debug-cannot-find-webview

Comment: please refer to the update for my test debugging steps.

Comment: I added the code to output the `error` parameter`. And its value is `{}`.