# Android remote debug cannot find webview?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-webview

I'm following https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ to debug a Cordova/ionic app. However, the following screen doesn't show the webview page? Are these error message relevant? Why the webview cannot be shown?

[image]

I closed all the chrome tabs. It will show the chrome pages if not closed.

Answer (score 0):

try to set your webcontentdebuggingenabled like this `mWebview.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)`

Comment: Cannot find this in cordova/ionic app?